# Get a specific response header (e.g., Content-Disposition) in React from an ASP.NET CORE Web Api

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am returning a file from a `WebAPI` controller. The `Content-Disposition` header value is automatically filled, and it contains also my filename.

My backend code looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("Download")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Download([FromQuery]CompanySearchObject req)
{
    string fileName = "SomeFileName_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Date.ToShortDateString() + ".csv";

    var result = await _myService.GetData(req);

    Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(result);

    return File(stream, "text/csv", fileName.ToString());
}
```

And on my frontend:

```
exportData(params).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log('Response Headers:', response.headers);
      const type = response.headers['content-type'];
      const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: type, encoding: 'UTF-8' });
      //const filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('"')[1];
      //alert(filename);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = 'file.xlsx';
      link.click();
      link.remove();
   });
};
```

[image]

But I'm struggling to fetch this data, because when I do console.log on frontend  I can not see this.. as you can see I logged response `console.log('Response Headers:', response.headers);` but only thing I see is:

[image]

Shouldn't this data be somewhere? I'm wondering how can I read value from `Content-Disposition` and get filename?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. My problem was CORS. If you are using it, you need to expose it like this in your configuration:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition"); // this is the important line
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

For Fetch Response Headers, it returns is an iterable, you have to loop through `response.headers` instead of `log response.headers object`.

Try code below:

```
response.headers.forEach(console.log);
console.log(response.headers.get('content-disposition'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is by looping through all the request headers until I match the specific header I'm looking for.

```
// Headers
private void GetSetCustomHeaders(ref string theUsername, ref string thePassword, ref string theAPIKey)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in this.Request.Headers)
        {
            string headerType = header.Key;
            string headerTypeUpperTrim = headerType.Trim().ToUpper();
            IEnumerable<string> headerValue = header.Value;
            string fullHeaderValue = "";
            bool isFirstHeaderValue = true;
            foreach (string headerValuePart in headerValue)
            {
                if (isFirstHeaderValue)
                {
                    fullHeaderValue = headerValuePart;
                    isFirstHeaderValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    fullHeaderValue = fullHeaderValue + Environment.NewLine + headerValuePart;
                }
            }
            if (headerTypeUpperTrim == "USERNAME")
            {
                theUsername = fullHeaderValue;
            }
            else if (headerTypeUpperTrim == "PASSWORD")
            {
                thePassword = fullHeaderValue;
            }
            else if (headerTypeUpperTrim == "APIKEY")
            {
                theAPIKey = fullHeaderValue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Error at 'GetSetCustomHeaders'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

In the example code above I'm looking for 'Username', 'Password' and 'APIKey'. They are passed through as `ref` parameters so If they're set in this method, they're set in the method calling this `GetSetCustomHeaders` method as well, because it references the same thing. So when I call this method initially my variables are set to `string.Empty`.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct I face this issue.Try that.

It can be resolve only server side(Back end side).You must be add back end response headers like this,

**Access-Control-Expose-Headers: [Content-Disposition , .....You can add  multiple heders]**

After that you can directly access this header using response.headers

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution to the one presented by @Kaca992, but for Azure Functions ([isolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) as opposed to in-process) and per function method:

```
    [Function(name: "FunctionMethod")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> FunctionMethod(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "my/route")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext context)
    {
        // await async work for get Request...
        // e.g. await getBlobFromService();

        // fyi: Get Content-Type from library with FilePath /w extension
        var provider = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        var success = provider.TryGetContentType("myfile.pdf", out string contentType); // Parse results in application/pdf.

        // Create response with Access-Control-Expose-Headers header and add Content-Disposition.       
        var okResponse = req.CreateResponse(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK);
        okResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType); // Assumes a successful parse.
        okResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
        okResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"myFile.pdf\"");
        return okResponse;

    }
```